# Foreign key on two columns referencing one pk in another table on Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

Is there a way to create a foreign key on two columns that reference the same PK in another table?

Both of these columns are related to the PK.

Here is what I have:

```
CONSTRAINT some_FK FOREIGN KEY (col1, col2) REFERENCES table(col_PK);
```

But I keep getting the following error:

> ORA-02256: number of referencing columns must match referenced columns

Comment: PK is player_ID. col1 is old_player_id and col2 is new_player_id so they are both technically linked to the PK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want two different foreign keys:

```
CONSTRAINT old_player_fk FOREIGN KEY (old_player_id) REFERENCES player(id), 
CONSTRAINT new_player_fk FOREIGN KEY (new_player_id) REFERENCES player(id)
```